# three.js animation above image - javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

http://ignite.la/advance1/
on the above URL, you can see the stars animation and the sphere reflecting the animation.
what i want to achieve, is [image]

, meaning that the reflecting sphere, is shown on the astronauts helmet. i cant seem to find any workaround to do it...
any tips or guidance would be great.
the astronaut is missing the webpage, find it here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCGTO.png
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to render it above the image if you make the shade of the helmet in the image transparent. At least that sounds like the easiest way to go here.

So you would replace the black color of the helmet with transparency (keep the rteflections of the arms and shoulders in there, partly transparent) and render the reflections along with the rest of the three.js-scene behind that.

Otherwise you'd need to very accurately fit the reflection onto the helmet (maybe using the stencil-buffer or something like that.

Comment: thanks for the input, do you have any resource or link/example? im pretty new to this...thanks

Comment: not really. I was imagining doing that in something like photoshop or gimp. Basically just cutting out the black area of the astronauts helmet and leaving it transparent.